# Chrome Application Cache deleted when going Offline

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker, offline-caching

I intend using a Service Worker to make a Web App available offline. The cache Storage shows the files when I have Internet Connection. However if I go Offline the cache seems to disappear. I do not have enabled the checkbox of Update on Reload in the Service Workers tab.

The fetch event of my service worker is:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Fetch', e.request.url);
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(e.request);
    })
  );
});
```

When I am Online the print for the console is:

An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED service-worker.js

However when I am offline the console ouptut is the following:

[ServiceWorker] Fetch https://cocoa.pythonanywhere.com/static/login/bootstrap/CSS/bootstrap.css
service-worker.js:113 [ServiceWorker] Fetch https://cocoa.pythonanywhere.com/static/login/logo.png
cocoa.pythonanywhere.com/:1 Adding master entry to Application Cache with manifest https://cocoa.pythonanywhere.com/static/login/Offline/HTML/manifesto
service-worker.js:113 [ServiceWorker] Fetch https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css
service-worker.js:113 [ServiceWorker] Fetch https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js
service-worker.js:113 [ServiceWorker] Fetch https://cocoa.pythonanywhere.com/static/login/js/app.js
service-worker.js:113 [ServiceWorker] Fetch https://cocoa.pythonanywhere.com/static/login/bootstrap/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js
service-worker.js:113 [ServiceWorker] Fetch https://cocoa.pythonanywhere.com/static/login/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js
service-worker.js:113 [ServiceWorker] Fetch https://cocoa.pythonanywhere.com/static/login/js/diem.js
cocoa.pythonanywhere.com/:1 Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: https://cocoa.pythonanywhere.com/static/login/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
app.js:2 CLIENT: service worker registration in progress.
app.js:4 CLIENT: service worker registration complete.

When I am Online the application tab looks:

[image: The Application Cache is poblated]

The Application Cache is poblated and the Service Worker registered.

When I am Offline it appears like this:

[image: The Cache is not poblated and the service worker not active]

The Cache is not poblated and the service worker not active.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the code that I needed for the service-worker in the following GitHub repository:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/tree/gh-pages/service-worker/custom-offline-page

The only thing I did was updating the Cahce File requested. In:

```
const OFFLINE_URL = 'name_of_the_file';
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you did. I have the same error and this doesn't help